# How to send a particular text view text to another activity using custom list view?

Tags: android, listview, textview

[image: As shown in image I want to get the text view text]

My only need is to send the `TextView` text to another `Activity` of the selected `ListView` item. I am using a custom `ListView` `Adapter` to get my data from web services using JSON parsing. With my current code, I am getting the text from the first `ListView` item everytime, no matter which item I click.

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Details bean : details) {
                nameList.add(bean.getResType());
                aero(details);


            }
        }
    }

    private void aero(final List<Details> mList) {

        for (Details bean : details) {

            final String urlChar = bean.getUrl();// may be the problem is here
            idno = String.valueOf(bean.getId()); // may be the problem is here

            if (bean.getResType().equals("Notes")) {
                final ListView listView;
                View view = getView();
                if (view != null) {
                    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list2);


                    CustomListViewAdapterNotes adapter = new CustomListViewAdapterNotes(getContext(),
                            R.layout.notes, mList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    // Assign adapter to ListView
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {


                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Main_Activity_for_Notes.class);
                            //add data to the Intent object
                            intent.putExtra("idnotes", idno);


                            intent.putExtra("urlchar", urlChar);


                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "Click ListItem Number " + idno, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                            startActivity(intent);


                        }


                    });
                }
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm a bit confused. Do you mean that, you have a `TextView` and you want to transfer it's text to the selected `ListView` item?

Comment: No, I have a text view in my list view and that text I want to display in another activity.But When I select an item in list view it always shows the first text of first text view .@McAwesomville

Comment: Log the position while clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Main_Activity_for_Notes.class);
                    //add data to the Intent object
                    intent.putExtra("idnotes", details.get(position).getId());


                    intent.putExtra("urlchar", details.get(position).getUrl());


                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Click ListItem Number " + details.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried it but getting nothing after  "Click ListItem Number "@IMRAN

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh Prosper K's answer is the exact solution. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks, after cleaning the project it is working @IMRAN

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh change mList with details ... i edit answer

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh Only replace these lines

Comment: @IMRAN both ways it is working details as well as mlist.

Answer (score 1):

> .With my code, I am getting the first item text every time, no matter
>   where I click.

First no need to initialize ListView, set Adapter for ListView, and adding setOnItemClickListener to ListView  inside `for-loop`.so just remove for-loop from code.

And to set clicked item of clicked row use `position` parameter if onItemClick method like inside `onItemClick` method:

```
Details bean= mList.get(position);
String urlChar = bean.getUrl(); 
String idno = String.valueOf(bean.getId());
```

pass `urlChar` and `idno` to other Activity using Intent.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys, but IMRAN answer is working fine so I accepted his answer @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh: if other answer is working then good but also improve your code by  removing `for-loop` from which is not required.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am also thinking why I put the for loop there@ρяσѕρєяK